# Member with no questions or upvoted answers got 11 reputation somehow?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Where does the 11 reputation for [this member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657486/marwan?tab=stats) come from?

Judging from the answer downvote, it appears as if he started with 13 reputation which makes no sense..

It's not accepted suggested edit, his activity [is clean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657486/marwan?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_all).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

The user does have an upvote - [see the reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657486/marwan?tab=reputation)

The upvote doesn't show on the info page as there is 2 x downvotes to one upvote

You can't get less than 1 rep, so user started off with 1, - and it stayed at 1 after the 2 x downvotes, then yesterday they got an upvote of 10 + 1 = 11

not sure if retro backvotes recalculate rep in a case like this though?

Comment: Thanks, as the answer is wrong I just didn't expect such a simple thing, lol..

Comment: yea possible a sympathy upvote?  I'm not sure enough about it to vote it either way, but I see someone nicely suggested user did remove their answer

Comment: Just to clarify: "not sure if retro backvotes recalculate rep in a case like this though?" - the result would be the same, we move forward chronologically when doing a recalc.

Comment: thanks @Nick, was never sure about that bit